# Only one page is generated with XSL-FO Page-Break Problem?

Tags: pdf-generation, xsl-fo

I am generating a PDF Document through XSL-FO. I have a simple xhtml structure like this:

```
<body>
<h2><center>Status</center></h2>
<table border="0">
<colgroup span="5"></colgroup>
<tr>
  <td><h4>Aktion</h4></td>
  <td><h4>Kommentar</h4></td>
  <td><h4></h4></td>
  <td><h4>Zeitpunkt</h4></td>
  <td><h4>Benutzer</h4></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><h5>Mappe archiviert</h5></td>
  <td><h5>QMSAA</h5></td>
   <td><h5></h5></td>
  <td><h5>26.07.2011  13:14</h5></td>
  <td><h5>Mustermann, Peter</h5></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><h5>Mappe als pdf gedruckt.</h5></td>
  <td><h5></h5></td>
  <td><h5></h5></td>
  <td><h5>26.07.2011  13:14</h5></td>
  <td><h5>Mustermann, Peter</h5></td>
</tr>
....
```

And i am using a xhtml to fop Stylesheet to convert this xhtml to an xsl-fo table. This works for most cases and in this case here i also get one page of content, but this should be at least two pages. While generating i get the following warnings:

> 30.08.2011 09:57:36 org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactoryConfigurator configure
>   INFO: Default page-height set to: 11in
>   30.08.2011 09:57:36 org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactoryConfigurator configure
>   INFO: Default page-width set to: 8.26in
>   30.08.2011 09:57:36 org.apache.fop.fo.flow.TableColumn bind
>   WARNUNG: table-layout="fixed" and column-width unspecified => falling back to pr
>   oportional-column-width(1)
>   30.08.2011 09:57:37 org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.inline.ContentLayoutManager 
>   WARNUNG: Title has no content
>   30.08.2011 09:57:37 org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.PageBreaker$1 notifyOverflow
>   WARNUNG: Content of the region-body on page 1 overflows the available area in bl
>   ock-progression dimension. (fo:page-sequence, no context info available)

The result i get is one page of content with one element overflowing the bottom of the page. But the rest of the content is lost, not second page is generated.

[image: The only page generated]

- What could be the problem here?
- Is it possible to have a pagebreak between two fo:table-row elements of one table?
- Why is no second page generated?

Comment: Can you show us the XSL-FO document (preferably trimmed down as much as possible)?

Comment: Unfortunately i can't because the system i'm working on is kind of a black box. I just have access to the xsl stylesheet which generates the FO code. I'll try to post that.

Comment: If you have the XML source and the XSLT stylesheet, can't you just forget about the "black box" and run a transformation from the command line?

Comment: Finally i got this FO Document out of the process: https://gist.github.com/1188165

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with the `keep-with-next.within-column` property on blocks within table cells in your FO document. If the "always" values are replaced with "auto", FOP 1.0 outputs four pages.

This could be a bug in FOP. I also processed the FO document with [XEP](http://www.renderx.com/tools/xep.html), and it produced four pages without complaining.

Maybe what you really want is `keep-together` on table rows?

I also noticed an empty `font-family` attribute on `<fo:page-sequence>`.

Comment: Thanks, but i just changed them all to "auto" and this does not change anything. I also deleted all attributes like that on the fo:block elements but i still get the same result.

Comment: What version of FOP are you using?

Comment: I was using Version 0.94 so far but due to your question i tried Version 1.0 and its libraries today. Still the same result.

Comment: this is working now, just missed to change the library paths inside the fop.bat thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your question, but you could use the open source [speedata Publisher](http://speedata.github.com/publisher/) which has automatic table breaking across pages. It is not an XSL-FO formatter but similar. Currently in German only (this will change in spring 2012) but I know that this is not a problem for you.